# Android: How do you fill a bitmap with color by volume?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a bitmap image that is of irregular shape that I fill with a certain color to simulate a "meter" of sorts. My current method uses a ColorMatrixColorFilter to replace color on the original bimtap, up to a percentage by bitmap height. What I'd really like to do is replace the color by volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could draw a filled bitmap overtop of the unfilled one, but use a clipping path based on the meter's level. If that can be done with a rectangular clip, it will be quite straightforward with Canvas.clipRect(float,float,float,float). Otherwise, you may have to specify a more general path and use Canvas.clipPath(Path). However, the clipPath is not anti-aliased, so it can look a bit lousy.

Another option is to draw the overlay directly with a custom Path, possibly using SVG path primitives for convenience. See this project: http://code.google.com/p/svg-android/ and specifically this method: http://svg-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/svgandroid/docs/com/larvalabs/svgandroid/SVGParser.html#parsePath(java.lang.String).

Comment: I'm calling Canvas.clipRect before I call Canvas.drawBitmap, the problem is that the top of the clip rect is based on a percentage of the height of the bitmap which was not calculated based on volume. What I think needs to happen is, I need to know how many pixels are in each row of the Bitmap, and the total number of pixels in the Bitmap, then calculate the height of the clip rect based on which row number meets the target volume percentage.

Comment: Interesting. OK, I don't think anything in the Android libraries will help you with that. You'll have to model the shape you are working with and calculate the "volume" (i.e. 2D area) yourself, then use that to compute to the appropriate row for clipping. A simplified heuristic may be sufficient, I don't think users would demand a perfect "water filling"-style progress animation.